# Search a github organization for repositories with a known PR name pattern

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3

One of our application can submit a github PR based on user request. User can decide to merge this PR or keep them unmerged.

Is there a way to search a git hub organization to find repositories with an unmerged PR. PR follows a naming pattern ie a static string with a dynamic part at the end.

```
ie. search git-org for all repos with a PR name like %auto_generated_pr_name_pattern%
```

Thanks,
San

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a [GitHub search](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues-and-pull-requests/), which does include [operators for merged or unmerged PR](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues-and-pull-requests/#search-based-on-whether-a-pull-request-is-merged-or-unmerged):

```
is:unmerged
```

Example: [`error` is:unmerged](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=error%20is%3Aunmerged&type=) matches closed issues and pull requests with the word "`error`".

You can add an [`in:title` operator](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues-and-pull-requests/#search-by-the-title-body-or-comments) to search for PR names.

On The GitHub API side, you have [Search Issues](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues), which, as its names does *not* suggest, allows to search PR as well.
Its search parameters include:

> `is`: Searches for items within repositories that match a certain state, such as open, closed, or merged.

As [Samuel Neff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118703/samuel-neff) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53200753/search-a-github-organization-for-repositories-with-a-known-pr-name-pattern/53202186?noredirect=1#comment105303742_53202186):

> OP also asked for within a specific organization, which you can add to search conditions with **`org:myorganization`**.

Comment: OP also asked for within a specific organization, which you can add to search conditions with `org:myorganization`

Comment: @SamuelNeff Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.